# Vue not updating after data change via axios

Tags: vue.js

I can load my data fine initially, and I have functions successfully getting called to modify my dictionary. However, Vue isn't showing the updates until I reload the page. I've read over the documentation and it seems my dictionary should be reactive since it's set initially in the data field. Am I doing something wrong or do I need to manually trigger a refresh?

An example usage would be a button that calls `add_link`.

Code:

```
var app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        domains: null,
    },
    mounted () {
        this.update()
    },
    methods: {
        update(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:5000/list').then(response => (this.domains = response.data));
        },
        add_link(domain,tag,url) {
            axios.get('http://localhost:5000/addlink?domain='+encodeURIComponent(domain)+'&tag='+encodeURIComponent(tag)+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(url))
            this.update()
        },
        remove_link(domain,tag) {
            axios.get('http://localhost:5000/removelink?domain='+encodeURIComponent(domain)+'&tag='+encodeURIComponent(tag))
            this.update()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be incomplete. No template shown? In addtion, does the Vue devtools show that `domains` has a value? Or not?

Comment: feels more like an asynchronous problem. Move `this.update()` into a `then`

Comment: @LannyBose Domains is set correctly via mounted - update gets called correctly, and page shows my data. Devtools does show domains. I’ll check in the AM to see if domains gets updated from the update in the add_links functions.

Comment: @A.L that was the solution! Thanks so much. I'm new to JS. I'll award the answer if you post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `axios` returns a promise, you either need to utilize `async await`

i.e.

```
    async add_link(domain,tag,url) {
        await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/addlink?domain='+encodeURIComponent(domain)+'&tag='+encodeURIComponent(tag)+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(url))
        this.update()
    },
```

or just put `this.update` into a then

```
    add_link(domain,tag,url) {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/addlink?domain='+encodeURIComponent(domain)+'&tag='+encodeURIComponent(tag)+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(url))
             .then( () => this.update() )

    },
```